ADC vs Service Account for OAuth2 Token for REST APIs
When I use Application Default Credentials to access GCP resources either through REST API or Java SDKs, I need to run re-authenticate every day using the "gcloud auth application-default login". Otherwise, I see the following error
Caught exception com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "reauth related error (invalid_rapt)",
"error_uri": "https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756",
"error_subtype": "invalid_rapt"
}
This may not be an acceptable method for the application to run in a production environment, for the user to re-authenticate everyday manually from a command line. Is there REST API Query/JAVA SDK corresponding to that application default login command, that can be run programmatically instead?

There are many ways you can use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable as part of your application. But the most recommended way is to attach a service account since providing a service account key may have security risks.
You may check also this github link for samples on how to use libraries of Google Java SDK
